# バナーの位置を下に下げたい

Tags: html, css, django

**現状**

画像のように、ページを開いたときにすでにバナーがメニュー下に重なり、見づらくなってしまっています。
いろいろ試してみたのですが、動きません。お力お貸しください！！
[こちら](https://teratail.com/questions/351674)とマルチポストしております。こちらで情報が更新・解決され次第、反映する予定です。どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**実現したいこと**

分かりにくいかもしれませんが、メニューバー（白い部分）とバナー（山の写真の部分）が重なっています。別のページにも同様のメニューバーがあるのですが、完全に文字が見えない部分もあります。スクロールすると当然重なるので、メニューバーに問題はないと思います。そこでバナーの位置を下に下げたいです。

**コード**

```html
{% load wagtailimages_tags wagtailcore_tags %}

{% image self.banner_img fill-900x400 as img %}

<div class="container-fluid bg-dark text-light p-5 " style="background-image: url('{{ img.url }}'); background-size: contain">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 text-center">
            <div class="row  justify-content-center">
                <div class="post-heading">
                    <h2>{{ self.title }}</h2>
                    <p class="subheading">{{ self.text|richtext }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load wagtailcore_tags %}

{% block content %}

<main class="main">
    <div class="contain">
        {% for block in page.content %}
            {% include_block block %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</main>

{% endblock %}
```

追記　[こちら](https://teratail.com/questions/351674)でレンダリングされるHTMLを追記しました。

Comment: 回答されるかたへ https://teratail.com/questions/351674

Comment: 最近、テラテイルはレスポンスが良くないため同内容でもこちらで聞いています。もちろん自分の勉強不足は理解したうえで、自分で解決できる場合はそのようにしています。素人なので教えていただきたいのですが、こういった別サイトでの重複質問はあまりよろしくないのでしょうか？

Comment: 別にマルチポストをするな、とは言いませんし、このコメントもそれを意図したものではありません。片方で解決していてもほかが放置されるようなことはありますので**ほかのかたへの**情報提供をメインとするものです。マルチポストの是非については [こちら](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2418/%e3%83%9e%e3%83%ab%e3%83%81%e3%83%9d%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e3%81%a8%e3%81%af%e3%81%aa%e3%82%93%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99%e3%81%8b-%e4%bd%95%e3%81%8b%e5%95%8f%e9%a1%8c%e3%81%8c%e3%81%82%e3%82%8b%e3%81%ae%e3%81%a7%e3%81%97%e3%82%87%e3%81%86%e3%81%8b/2419#2419) にあるとおりです。マルチポスト時のマナーについてもこちらに紹介されているので是非ご一読ください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。一読いたしました。そういった問題点があるということを理解せずにマルチポストしておりました。このように気付ける機会を頂きありがとうございます。早急に対応いたします。

Comment: ちなみにこの質問の状況だと以前の2つの質問は解決しているようですが、自己解決したならその内容を自己回答されると情報共有が出来て有意義ですのでよろしくお願いします。

Comment: htmlとCSSのデザインの問題であるならばテンプレートのソースを表示するのではなく、質問編集にあるスニペット機能を用いてHTMLCSSで再現をするとより回答が得られやすいと思います。

Comment: kunif様　ご回答ありがとうございます。承知いたしました。

Comment: keitaro_so様　ご回答ありがとうございます。スニペット機能確認いたしました。使ってみたところbootstrapの埋め込みやジャンゴコードは読み込まれませんでした。今後HTML、CSSの質問をするときは使う前提で質問したいと思います。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: いえこの問題の本質はHTMLとCSSでいかに実現するかが問題で、Djangoコードはそれが実現できた場合に実装すればいいです。また外部の質問サイトに追記した内容はきちんとこちらの質問を編集して内容を転載をしてください。

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrapを使用して、HTMLを組んでいました。しかし呼び出すBootstrapのcssファイルはダウンロード型ではなく、リンク貼り付け型だったのでいくら変更を加えても変わらなかったようです。

解決法としましては、Bootstrapファイルをプロジェクトフォルダー内に追加、リンク書き換え、cssを変更で解決することができました。

まだまだ初心者であるため、灯台下暗しな質問をしてしまいました。みなさまご協力ありがとうございました。